# Zend Framework 2 Access Service via Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework2

Additional to my previous question [How to access a variable in my Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716752/zend-framework2-how-to-access-a-variable-in-my-service)
I am now struggling to access the Service from my View Helper via an Ajax Request.

I have added a further method in the BookmarkAdvertService() to add a Bookmark.

```
    public function saveAdvertBookmark($advertId)
    {
        $bookmark = new Bookmark();
        $userId = $this->getUserEntity()->getId();
        $bookmark->setUserId($userId);
        $bookmark->setAdvertId($advertId);

        # write new bookmmark to database tbl bookmark
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($bookmark);
        $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
    }
```

In my partial I have added a link

```
 <?php if($bookmarkStatus==true){ ?>
           Saved !
           <a href="#" id="remove-bookmark">Remove Bookmark</a>
 <?php }else{ ?>
           <a href="#" id="add-bookmark">Add Bookmark</a>
 <?php }?>

 <script>
 $("#add-bookmark").click (function () {
            $.ajax({    
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/add-bookmark',
            success: function(response) {
                    window.location.reload(true);       
            }
        });
    });
});
<script>
```

1. Is it possible to access the Method in the Service via the Ajax
   request? So far I have always only access the Controller via an Ajax
   Request.
2. I suppose I have to hand over the advertID via Ajax as well   data: { id: advertId }, meaning I have to write and read out the advertId via jQuery as well or is there another way to get it in my Service?

It is probably a really stupid question, but I still struggle when I use a Service. Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an action in your controller that will use that service and return the result back to the jquery script. In zf2, the requests get dispatched to a matched controller-action, a really raw example should look like this:

```
public function addBookmarkAction()
{
    $id = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('id');
    $this->getServiceLocator()->get("BookmarkAdvertService")->saveAdvertBookmark($id);
    return $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(200);
}
```

And you should add the id to a query parameter of the url (also update the router accordingly). Or send the request via POST and retreive from there in your controller.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Alright, so I can not jump straight to the Service, if I understand you right. Is that 100% sure? It would be too bad if that's the case... Otherwise I will try to implement your solution.

Comment: No, you can't. zf2 in designed in that way, every request will be first tried to match a router and get the controller and action if there is a match.

Comment: Oh, ok and just to confirm again, I do need a route for an AJAX Link?

Comment: Yes, you need a route in order to match that request to a controller-action.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much. I will have a look how to get the right route for it and if I can access the Service in the end. You pointed me in the right direction, hopefully I will now be able to walk :-)

Comment: No problem! glad to help and hope you can get your things to work :)

Comment: Very sorry, one last question to it, should a Ajax Link be a Segment or a Literal Route? I am never quite sure about these routes...

Comment: if you plan to pass the id with get, you should go with segment as it will allow you to use variables in the url. Otherwise if you send the request as post, you can use Literal.

Comment: Great explanation. Route is working and as soon I will find out how to access the Service in the Controller (I suppose I should really inject it) I should have the solution. Great help from you, my first practise project is now nearly done.